# SOQL count of records of the inner query

Tags: salesforce, soql

I want to know how many records an SOQL query returns. (Not `select count(Id) from table`, Here instead of table I have to use an SOQL query itself)
In SQL we do this as `select count(*) from (select blah blah....)`.
How can I do this in SOQL.

Comment: Its salesforce Object Query Language. Similar to SQL but with less features.

Comment: Can you explain why you can't `count()` on table? What is your use case?